# product item quantity can't be zero in bundle product

Tags: magento

Magento 2.4

product item quantity can't be zero in bundle product.

Change to 0 in front end and add it to cart

When check out the cart, i found the item's qty is 1 instead of 0

How to deal with it?

How to make the qty=0, showing correct information in cart ?